# Weak convergence + convergence of the norm implies strong convergence in Orlicz spaces

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, calculus-of-variations, optimal-transportation

It is known [1, proposition 3.32] and a classical trick in PDEs that, in any uniformly convex Banach space $X$, weak convergence $x_n\rightharpoonup x$ together with convergence of the norm $\|x_n\|_X\to \|x\|_X$ implies strong convergence $\|x_n-x\|_X\to 0$.
The typical example arising in PDEs is that of $L^p$ spaces, which are uniformly convex Banach spaces if and only if $1<p<+\infty$. It is also known that this property fails for $p=1$, see [1, exercise 4.19], probably also for $p=\infty$ as well (although I don't have a counterexample at hand).

> **Question:** does anyone know of a similar result in Orlicz spaces? I-e if $\Phi:\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb R^+$ is a "good" $N$-function (satisfying all the properties one might need such as $\Delta_2$ condition and so on) and $f_n\in L^\Phi$ is a sequence converging weakly $f_n\rightharpoonup f$ such that $\|f_n\|_{L^\Phi}\to \|f\|_{L^\Phi}$ then in fact $\|f_n-f\|_{L^\Phi}\to 0$?

I am mostly interested in the case of a smooth, bounded domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^d$ with the Orlicz space $L\log^+ L(\Omega)$.
For example, my wildest dream is as follows: if $\rho_n$ is a sequence of $L^1$ probability measures converging weakly $L^1$ to some limit $\rho$ and such that the convergence in entropy $\int_\Omega \rho_n(x)\log\rho_n(x) \mathrm d x\to \int_\Omega \rho(x)\log\rho(x) \mathrm d x $ holds, then $\rho_n\to \rho$ in $L \log L$. Or at least $\rho_{n_k}(x)\to \rho(x)$ pointwise a.e. for a posisble subsequence $n_k\to \infty$. But this is probably too much to hope for. I am still wondering if anything can be said in this case?

---

[1] Haïm Brézis, *Functional analysis, Sobolev spaces and partial differential equations*, Universitext, New York: Springer, pp. xiii+599 (2011), [MR2759829](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2759829), [Zbl 1220.46002](https://zbmath.org/1220.46002).

Comment: The Boltzmann entropy is only l.s.c. in the weak topology of $L^1 (\Omega)$. Do you have some situations where we have the convergence $\int_\Omega \rho_n(x)\log\rho_n(x) \mathrm d x\to \int_\Omega \rho(x)\log\rho(x) \mathrm d x$?

Comment: Well, that's the whole point: for some independent reason I'm able to prove that the entropy converges. and I want to improve the convergence, i-e $\rho_n\to\rho$ should hold in a stronger sense than I initially assumed.

Comment: Let me just give a heuristic reasoning as to why this may hold true: it is well known that lack of strong convergence can only arise form oscillations. But, wild oscillations tend to encode lots of information in the sense of 1/0 bits in information theory. Such bits correspond to high entropy. But since $\limsup E(\rho_n)\leq E(\rho)$ the sequence cannot contain too much information, thus it should not oscillate too fast, and converge better than expected. OK sure, this is a very very rough picture, but I think there's some truth to it and I'm trying to make put this intuition on solid ground

Comment: Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Comment: let me just mention that this property is known as Kadets-Klee or Radon-Riesz property

Comment: @erz thank you, I was not aware that this had a name. good to know!

Answer (score 6):

There's a famous trick attributed to Minty (sometimes also to Browder and Lions) which allows to recover at least a.e. convergence when you're able to pass to the limit through an increasing non-linearity (typically $x\mapsto x^p$). As I guess you read french (right ?) you can check " Exercice 2 "  [in that document](https://www.ljll.math.upmc.fr/%7Emoussa/pdf/enseignements/td_af_1_bonus.pdf).

I don't know if's applicable in your example but it is worth giving a shot (and it's friday night, so I let you check !). I would believe avoiding the regions in which $(\rho_n)_n$ gets too closer to $0$ (which are actually OK as far oscillations are concerned), you should be able to recover an increasing setting for your non-linearity.

EDIT:

If you manage to prove furthermore that the integral of $(\log(\rho_n)\rho)_n$ converges to the integral of $\log(\rho)\rho$, you should be able to recover a.e. convergence. Note that this extra assumption is somehow weaker than the one you have. If indeed you have both, you consider $f_n:=(\log(\rho_n)-\log(\rho))(\rho_n-\rho)$. Since $\log$ is non-decreasing, you have $f_n\geq 0$. Expanding the expression you get by linearity (and using both assumptions above) that
$$ \int_\Omega f_n \rightarrow 0.$$
Since $f_n\geq 0$, the previous is in fact the convergence $(f_n)_n\rightarrow 0$ in $L^1(\Omega)$. Extracting a subsequence you recover a.e. convergence for $(f_n)_n$ and using that $\log$ is increasing, this a.e. convergence can be transfered to $(\rho_n)_n$ itself.

Comment: Hi Ayman, funny to bump into you, I'm a friend and coauthor of Clément Cancès, and I'm currently trying to apply your "time compactness" trick with him and Boris. Small world. I'm well aware of Minty's trick, but unfortunately the entropy $z\log z$ is not monotone. And I don't think I have any other angle of attack for my speciic problem, the $L^p$ norms are unfortunately out of reach in my particular problem. Thanks antway, I appreciate you taking the time to answer and I hope we can meet in person some day. À plus!

Comment: Ah ! That's indeed funny ! About your problem, I was hoping for some kind of localization argument because for $\varepsilon>0$ and suitable $C_\varepsilon>0$, $z\log z + C_\varepsilon z$ is indeed increasing for $z>\varepsilon$, but it's not that clear that you can indeed localize without oscillations $\rho_n \geq \varepsilon$. I'll think about that next week and tell you if I get to anything new ! Bon week-end :)

Comment: In fact it's the increasingness of $\log$ which matters (see above the edit of my answer), however you need an extra estimate on $(\rho \log(\rho_n)_n$ to close the argument.

Comment: Merci Ayman. Unfortunately for my specific prolem I really don't see how to get started on $\int \rho\log\rho_n\to \int\rho\log\rho$. The entropy just hows up as a whoe, part of a functional that I'm minimizing, but that's it. So unless I manage to get some additional information I'm stuck. And I've tried hard, already!